# Get the list of result from first sql query and execute second query on the result of list of first query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So, I am working with redshift and SQL for the first time. I have run into this problem due to my limted knowledge of SQL.

I have this first query which return me tables with the columnA. (TableX, TableY... etc)

```
SELECT tablename
FROM PG_TABLE_DEF
WHERE ("column" = 'columnA');
```

Also I have this second query which returns me all the rows from the table containig certain value of columnA.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableX 
WHERE columnA='123934'
```

What I want to achieve is take the result from the first query which is list of tables, and for each table run the second query i.e. get the rows with value of columnA=123934 for each table returned from first query.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is done using dynamic SQL. Dynamic queries let you run a query from a string.
I am not an Redshit user but to generate the SQL string you need to run you could use the following query:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '||tablename ||' WHERE ColumnA= ''123934''; '
FROM PG_TABLE_DEF
WHERE ("column" = 'columnA');
```

You can try running it manually.